# _CrtMem* and the debug heap

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks

When I use the following code, it detects a memory leak. How can I make it not?

```
_CrtMemState startState;
_CrtMemState endState;
_CrtMemState temp;

_CrtMemCheckpoint(&startState);
const char* foo = "I'm not leaking memory! Stop saying I am!";
_CrtMemCheckpoint(&endState);

_CrtMemDifference(&temp, &startState, &endState);    // Returns true. Wtf?
```

Comment: Does it detect a leak if the codes is changed to 

const char[]

Comment: No repro, even after calling _CrtSetDbgFlag().  I didn't expect one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cut and pasted your code and tested it on my machine under VS2008 and _CrtMemDifference returns 0 ...

As the oft heard adage goes: "Works on my machine" ;)

Edit:  Have you got multiple threads running?  Is it possible another thread has allocated something between the 2 _CrtMemCheckpoint calls?

Comment: Never mind, it was my fault. Unrelated code. Thanks for your quick response.